# JavaScript syntax inside jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not able to use `document.getElementById` inside jQuery.

```
<div id="div1" style="height:200px;width:300px;border:1px solid black;background-color:yellow;">
  This is some text in the div.
  <p>This is a paragraph in the div.</p>
  <p>This is another paragraph in the div.</p>
  <h1 id="apple" style="display:none;">This is another paragraph in the div.</h1>
</div>
<br>

<button>Empty the div element</button>
```

This works-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
         $("#div1").empty();

    });
});
```

Even this works fine-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){

         document.getElementById('apple').style.display='block';
    });
});
```

But problem is in this-

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
         $("#div1").empty();
         document.getElementById('apple').style.display='block';
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kt9ypccp/)

Could anybody explain the reason?

Comment: How do you get an element that isn't there, you've removed it by emptying it's parent ?

Comment: Is `apple` supposed to be inside `Div1`?? If so, you erased it with `empty()`

Comment: is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/kt9ypccp/1/

Comment: The HTML is an integral part of the question. Please include all relevant data directly in the question instead of relying on off-site resources to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've removed the contents of `div1` so `apple` no longer exists in the document.

Therefore, when you later call `document.getElementById('apple')`, you will not get any element back.

Answer (score 2):

That is because the element has been removed at the previous line. You can do what you want like this (but you should probably find another way) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
         var apple = document.getElementById('apple');
         $("#div1").empty().append(apple);
         apple.style.display='block';
    });
});
```